# Javascript - Unable to save recorded screen using MediaRecorder API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mediarecorder

I'm trying into chrome console this code to record the desktop or a selected tab of the browser.

```js
( async () => { 
    const displayOptions = {
      video: {
        cursor: "never"
      },
      audio: {
        echoCancellation: true,
        noiseSuppression: true,
        sampleRate: 44100
      }
    }
    
    const chunks = [];
    
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayOptions);
    const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    recorder.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e);
    recorder.start();

    recorder.onstop = e => {
        const blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: 'video/mp4'});
        const el = document.createElement('a');
        el.download = 'testvideo.mp4';
        el.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        el.click();
    }

})();
```

When I run the script, it will give me the ability to select the source to capture. I've tried to record few seconds and when I stop the capture, it will open the download prompt. The problem is that the output file is empty and quicktime or VLC are unable to open it because it's lenght is of zero seconds. Is there something wrong in the code? How I can save the file as `mp4` correctly? If I want to use the code inside a node CLI script to target a browser tab, will it work or I need to use it in combo with puppeteer?

Comment: Reading [the documentation (in this case for `ondataavailable`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable) is never a bad idea: _"The `Blob` containing the media data is available in the `dataavailable` event's `data` property."_ - You're pushing the event object into `chunks` -> `.push(e.data)`

Comment: I saw the typo, I need to pass `e.data` to the `.push()` function right?

Comment: @Andreas solved the output file issue but it will be saved without the audio, I need to modify the settings?